# Mouseover from Fusion table

Tags: javascript, mouseover, google-fusion-tables

I have a website (www.auscem.com) with a link below the table to a Fusion table map. Currently, markers on the map are clickable to get the infoWindow, but I would like to make them mouseover instead. The present script is (slightly abbreviated):

```
var map;
var layer;
var tableid = xxxxxxx;

function load()
{
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapDiv'),
{
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.274, 133.775),
  zoom: 4, //zoom
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP //the map style
});

layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(tableid, {suppressInfoWindows: false});
layer.setQuery("SELECT 'Latitude' FROM " + tableid);
layer.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addListener(layer, "click", function(event)
{
  document.getElementById('siteInfo').innerHTML = event.infoWindowHtml;
});

}
 // execute this
window.onload = load;
```

I've tried all sorts of things,, but have not gotten it working.

Ideas would be most welcome....

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [FusionTips](http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontips/) utility library?  It does tooltips based off of FusionTables data.  You should be able to convert it to doing InfoWindows, I'm not sure how efficient it will be.

Comment: Yes, that was the one I tried most to adapt. But I didn't get it going. I was prepared to accept the 'tooltip' look until it worked, then I hoped to use a genuine infoWindow. But...no luck.

Comment: Well, maybe you could have shared that fact with us and shown what you tried.

Comment: There were 7 or 8 variants, and I didn't keep all of the ones I tried. But essentially, I replaced the addListener 'click' line with addListener 'mouseover' and then 'mouseout'

Comment: That won't work.  The FusionTablesLayer doesn't support those events natively, only the click event.  Read and follow the documentation for the FusionTips utility library.  You will have to understand and modify it to open InfoWindows instead of tooptips.

Comment: I know that already, which is why I'm looking for help. Looking at the docs, I find a mouseover event that has this note:
This event is fired when the mouse over a fusion feature. Contains: infoWindowHtml, latLng, row.

Comment: The fact that you knew this already wasn't very clear from your question, you have basically wasted both our time but not explaining what you had done.

Comment: Well, you certainly are no help. It would be good if you could put down your aggressive attitude and be more useful.